# routing navigate method not redirecting to targeted component

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing, angular-routing

I have an issue with using routing navigate method of angular. 
I have two components : LoginComponent and HomeComponent.
When I click on the button in "login.component.html", I want to be redirected to "home.component.html".

- **app.module.ts**

  ```
  import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
  import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
  import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
  import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
  import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
  import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

  const routes: Routes = [
    {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent}
  ];

  @NgModule({
    declarations: [
      AppComponent,
      HomeComponent,
      LoginComponent
    ],
    imports: [
      BrowserModule, RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
  })
  export class AppModule { }
  ```
- **login.component.html**

```html
 <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="goHome();" class="clickable">Home</button>
```

- **home.component.html**

```html
<p>
  home works!
</p>
```

The URL changes but it remain in the same component page.

- **login.component.ts**

  > ```
  > import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
  > import { Router } from '@angular/router';
  >
  > @Component({
  >   selector: 'app-login',
  >   templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  >   styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
  > })
  > export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  >
  >   constructor(private router:Router) { }
  >
  >   ngOnInit() {
  >   }
  >
  >    goHome() {
  >     this.router.navigate(['home']);
  >   }
  > }
  > ```

Comment: check if the router-outlet tag is commented

Answer (score 7):

Make these additions:

`<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="goHome();" class="clickable">Home</button>`

```
    goHome() {
    this.router.navigate(['home']);
  }
```

or via `<a>`.

```
<a [routerLink]="['/home']">home</a>
```

If necessary, remove `/` if you intend to be appended to the current route instead.

Answer (score 3):

first of all you need to define routes in app.routing.modules.ts like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'Home', loadChildren: () => import('./Home/Home.module').then(m => m.HomeModule) },
  {
path: '',
redirectTo: '',
pathMatch: 'full'
}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

you need to do this in your Login ts file:

```
goHome() {
    this.router.navigate(['/home']);
  }
```

and

```
<button (click)="goHome()">Home</button>
```

in Login Html file

Or just:

```
<button [routerLink]="'home'">Home</button>
```

in Login html file.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to load multiple routes in your template then you can use in your app.component template:

```
 <router-outlet> <router-outlet>
```

If you want to load nested routes, then try to use:

```
constructor(private routes: ActivatedRoute) {}
|
|
|
this.route.navigate(['home'], {relativeTo: this.routes});
```

and use the routerLink directive in your a tag and then pass the route which you specified in your path

hope it's useful.

Answer (score 0):

Add the routerLink to the button

```
<button routerLink="/home">Home</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't need to write  these method in ts file

```
goHome(){
      this.router.navigate(['home']);
     }
```

just add routerLink attribute in button tag

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="goHome();" class="clickable" routerLink="/home">Home</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Verify the following the steps for proper navigation

Step 1: By default, the RouterModule is imported in the app-routing.module.ts

Step 2: Check whether you have this below code in your app.component.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Step 3: Define the correct path in app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'Home', component: HomeComponent,
  }, 
];
```